# I'm trying to put 2 views on top and 2 two on bottom but doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout

I want something like that

- Linear Layout - vertical
- Linear Layout - Horizontal
- Frame Layout
- Frame Layout
- Linear Layout - horizontal
- Frame Layout
- Frame Layout

view1  |  view2

view3  |  view4

What should I do to fix this code

### Code

```
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static LinearLayout padrao;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    padrao = findViewById(R.id.padrao);
    videoUnico();
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
private void videoUnico() {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams ll = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    padrao.removeAllViews();

    FrameLayout view = new FrameLayout(this);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    view.setLayoutParams(ll);
    ll.setMargins(16, 16, 16, 16);
    padrao.addView(view, ll);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            viewDois();
        }
    });

}

private void viewDois() {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, .5f);


    params.setMargins(16, 16, 16, 16);
    padrao.removeAllViews();

    FrameLayout view = new FrameLayout(this);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    padrao.addView(view, params);

    FrameLayout view2 = new FrameLayout(this);
    view2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    padrao.addView(view2, params);

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            viewTres();
        }
    });
}

private void viewTres() {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, .5f);
    padrao.removeAllViews();
    params.setMargins(16, 16, 16, 16);

    FrameLayout view = new FrameLayout(this);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    padrao.addView(view, params);

    FrameLayout view2 = new FrameLayout(this);
    view2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    padrao.addView(view2, params);

    FrameLayout view3 = new FrameLayout(this);
    view3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    padrao.addView(view3, params);

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            viewQuatro();
        }
    });

}

private void viewQuatro() {

    padrao.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



    LinearLayout linearHorizonteBaixo = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearHorizonteBaixo.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,.5f));
    linearHorizonteBaixo.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    LinearLayout linearHorizonteCima = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearHorizonteCima.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,.5f));
    linearHorizonteCima.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    FrameLayout view = new FrameLayout(this);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);


    FrameLayout view2 = new FrameLayout(this);
    view2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    linearHorizonteCima.addView(view);
    linearHorizonteCima.addView(view2);

    FrameLayout view3 = new FrameLayout(this);
    view3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    FrameLayout view4 = new FrameLayout(this);
    view4.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    linearHorizonteBaixo.addView(view3);
    linearHorizonteBaixo.addView(view4);

    padrao.addView(linearHorizonteCima);
    padrao.addView(linearHorizonteBaixo);
   }

}
```

Xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/padrao"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

This is the entire class 
I'm using methods to call the other layout
But my problem is when im trying to create two linear layout inside one 
and also get this error 
`java.lang.ClassCastException: 
android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams 
cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams`

Comment: Please.paste the entire code to correctly understand your issue..

Comment: Do you need the code of this as a program in java or as XML?

Comment: I need this as a program in java

Comment: Please paste the entire class what you have..

Comment: Look now I paste the entire class

Comment: Thank you.. Give me some time, I'll get back to you with an answer.

Comment: Thanks man. If u need I paste my xml code

Comment: Okay you can paste it.. I might have a use of it.

Comment: which line causes the exception?

Comment: In method viewQuatro(), but i dont know which line

Answer (score 0):

this code in XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:weightSum="2">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="View2" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="View1" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="View4" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="View3" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```